# html5 required not working on android 2.1

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I have code that is working good in chrome, safari firefox. But when I upload to server abd view on mobile the input with the required field doesn't fire the 'please fill in a the fields message'. Totally ignores it. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong. I am using jquery mobile 1.02b.

```
for(var a = 0;a < $(this).val();a++) {
 $("#boxnumber").append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="boxamount" class="ui-input-text">Enter box ' + (a + 1) + ' number:</label><input type="text" name="boxamount-' + a + '-no" id="boxamount-' + a + '-no" class="boxamount ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-a" required /></div>')
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. It's simply [not supported](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) on Android yet.

But since you are using jQuery already, you might want to try out [h5Validate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/h5Validate) for simulating HTML5 Form Validation support.

You can also try out [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/index.html) for details of HTML5 support of your browser.

Comment: emboss thank you very much for the heads up. But does h5Validate actually work on android?

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I haven't tried but since it's Javascript and a plugin to jQuery I think there is a good chance it should.

Comment: emboss I have been trying to get this to work either with browser, chrome,safari etc but still no go. I wonder if you have the time you would check a question I raised and either comment there or here. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234336/jquery-mobile-h5validate-help