# jQuery Mobile h5Validate help

Tags: android, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I have started to develop using jQuery mobile and for validation on the android because of lack of html5 support, thought I would try h5Validate. Now try as I might, I cannot get this to work. I have posted my inputs and if someone could just show me a mark-up for this I would be grateful. Thanks

h5Validate link:

[`http://ericleads.com/h5validate/?name=`](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/?name=)

html

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
 <label for="slider">No of Boxes *</label>
 <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" data-h5-errorid="boxnumber" title="Required: Please enter your box(es)." required data-track-theme="a" value="0" min="0" max="10" required />
</div>

<div id="boxnumber" class="ui-state-error message" style="display:none;" data-theme="b">
```

script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#login').h5Validate({
  errorClass:'black'
 });
});
</script>
```

css

```
.ui-state-error {
    background-color:#BB1100;
    color:white;
}

#login input, label {
    float:left;
}
.message {
    margin-left:1em;
    width:20em;
    border:1px;
    padding:2px;
    float:left;
    font-size:10pt;
}
.black {
    background-color:#111111;
    color:silver;
}
```

Comment: Is this question unreasonable as to not warrant a response? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The new input types were being ignored by h5Validate. I've fixed that. If you still have trouble, let me know. You can file bug tickets here: https://github.com/dilvie/h5Validate/issues?sort=created&direction=desc&state=open

Try upgrading to the latest h5Validate.